# Conditional flow based on value of Single

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

How do I have conditional flow based on the value of Single? For eg., in the following example, I want the chain to end if getNextAction(nodeId) results in an empty action, proceed otherwise.
Each of the methods return Single, not Observable. And apparently, filter only works with Observables.

```
          getNextAction(nodeId)
           .flatMap(action -> {
               if (action.isEmpty()) {
                   sendResponse("");
               }
               return Single.just(action);
           })
           //.filter(action -> !action.isEmpty())
           .flatMap(action -> prepareAction(action, nodeId)
            .subscribe(response -> sendResponse(transform(response)));
```

Answer (score 0):

one approach might be:

1. `flatMap` the result of `getNextAction()` into a `Completable`
2. inspect the action to either complete the stream immediately, or compose a set of actions to be completed (e.g. preparing the action and sending the response)

that might look something like this:

```
getNextAction(nodeId)
    .flatMapCompletable(action -> {
      if(action.isEmpty()) {
        return Completable.complete();
      } else {
        return Completable.fromAction(() -> {
          // prepareAction()...
          // sendResponse()...
        });
      }
    })
    .subscribe(
        ()    -> System.out.println("## onComplete()"),
        error -> System.out.println("## onError(" + error.getMessage() + ")")
    );
```

(the above assumes that `getNextAction()` returns a `Single<String>`)

if nothing else, i hope it inspires some thought.